# TransactionSynchronizationRegistry vs TransactionSynchronizationManager

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have an application running no weblogic with ejb, with JTA provided by WLS. Now I am trying to adapt all application to work in tomcat without ejb, using spring instead. Also will use JPATransactionManager that spring provides, instead of JTA.

I used to use `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.getTransactionKey()` in order to get tx object and use it for cache purposes. Now I am adapting spring and I have `TransactionSynchronizationManager` of spring, where I can't findv such an API.

My question is - do you know some analog of `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.getTransactionKey()` in spring ?

Or where I could get some unique object with info about transaction?

Comment: I found something similar in JPATransactionManager - doGetTransaction(), however it is protected

Comment: Comments are not for details about your question. Just [edit] the question and put those details in the body of the question. You may also be asked to provide some relevant source code that reproduces what you are seeing.

Comment: Can you please help in this following query:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75905572/retrieving-current-transaction-from-spring-platformtransactionmanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by using some generated logical transaction ID. This transaction ID is stored by calling `TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(key, value)` and retrieved by `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(key)`.

However it will not work properly in case if transaction interleaving.

Assume that you have flow with **transaction interleaving** when upstream transaction A is suspended whereas downstream transaction B is running.

In case if in two this transaction you try to store transaction ID with some key as mentioned above, you could have an issue that you mixing your resources.

In this case recommended use **ResourceHolderSupport** which is responsible to listen various states of transaction and bind or unbind resources.

In our case assume that tx1 is stores **resource** = "txID", "123456", and tx1 suspended because tx2 is starting to run, resource holder will unbind **resource** and when tx1 will be resumed - it will bind it again.